# How to judge a tile in screen

Tags: android, canvas, dictionary

I draw a lot of image slices on canvas when I move the the canvas,I want the slice outside of the screen not to draw.

Answer (score 0):

I would put something like this in your onDraw to tell it not to only draw if its on screen.

```
if (imageslice.getX() > 0 + screenXOffset 
    && imageslice.getX < screenWidth + screenXOffset){

  //Draw your image

 }
```